# php while loop if to do for first row else to do for second row?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I have while loop from mysql , i try to do some thing for first result under if else do other thing for second result etc....

my code this

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_row)) {
$rowid = $row['rowid'];
$number = $row['number'];
$result = $number - 1;
if ($result != '0') {
// for only first result != 0 do this
require('result.php');
$i++;
// for all other results != 0 too do this
$edit_row = "UPDATE rows SET status = 'Ok' WHERE rowid = '$rowid'";
mysql_query($edit_row);
} elseif ($result == '0') {
$edit_row = "UPDATE rows SET status = 'Not Ok' WHERE rowid = '$rowid'";
mysql_query($edit_row);
} 
}
```

Comment: you can use simple condition $i==1 for first result and $i>1 for other results

Answer (score 1):

Simply can use `$i` by increasing it. Do for first row when `$i == 1` else do other. Example:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_row)) {
    $rowid = $row['rowid'];
    if ($i == 1) { //Do for first row when $i == 0
        $i++; //Increase the value of $i
        require('result.php');
        $edit_row = "UPDATE rows SET status = 'Ok' WHERE rowid = '$rowid'";
        mysql_query($edit_row);
    } else { //Do other when $i > 1
        $edit_row = "UPDATE rows SET status = 'Not Ok' WHERE rowid = '$rowid'";
        mysql_query($edit_row);
    }
}
```

Also suggest you to use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead `mysql`.